# Create a new column to my data frame that specify which icc>0.8 in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to create a new column to my data frame that specify which icc>0.8. I used the code below.

```
ID=c(1,2,3,4,5)
ICC=c(0.67899, 0.34213, 0.86969, 0.98373, 0.6421)
df=data.frame(ID, ICC)
df %>%
  mutate(., Prop= ifelse(ICC %in%  0.8:1.0, "GOOD","BAD"))->df2
df2
```

When I run this code, I got BAD for every of my ID. However, I want this:

```
ID=c(1,2,3,4,5)
ICC=c(0.67899, 0.34213, 0.86969, 0.98373, 0.6421)
Prop=c("BAD", "BAD","GOOD","GOOD","BAD") 
df3=data.frame(ID, ICC,Prop)
df3
```

Comment: `Prop= ifelse(ICC >  0.8,"GOOD","BAD")`

Comment: Also, see what `0.8:1.0` gives.